# What is purpose of System class?

Tags: java

I just looked through some code and saw `System` in a lot of places

```
System.out.println();
System.exit();
```

etc.

Is the main purpose of this class to provide system resources? Do system resources mean Java-related resources here?

Comment: Check the docs before asking please.

Comment: You should invest minimum effort to check API documentation

Comment: Used to describe the configuration of the current working environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `java.lang.System` class contains several useful utilities for mostly used operation. `System` class cannot be instantiated.

Facilities provided by `System`:

- standard output
- error output streams
- standard input and access to externally defined properties and environment variables.
- A utility for quickly copying particular portion of an array.
- used to loading files and libraries.

Standard Fields of `System` class are:

- `static PrintStream err` -- "standard" error output stream.
- `static InputStream in` --  "standard" input stream.
- `static PrintStream out` --  "standard" output stream.

Answer (score 1):

That is clearly mention on `javadoc`.

> Among the facilities provided by the System class   are standard
>   input, standard output, and error output streams;   access to
>   externally defined properties and environment   variables; a means of
>   loading files and libraries; and a utility   method for quickly
>   copying a portion of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Java has tons of documentation on their libraries. Try checking [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) out.

Basically, as it says on their site, System is for standard I/O.